# How do you control float formatting when using DataFrame.to_markdown in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use [`DataFrame.to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) with a dataframe that contains float values that I'd like to have rounded off. Without `to_markdown()` I can just set `pd.options.display.float_format` and everything works fine, but `to_markdown` doesn't seem to be respecting that option.

Repro:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [42.42, 99.11234123412341234, -23]])
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
print(df)
print()
print(df.to_markdown())
```

outputs:

```
   0  1   2
0  1  2   3
1 42 99 -23

|    |     0 |       1 |   2 |
|---:|------:|--------:|----:|
|  0 |  1    |  2      |   3 |
|  1 | 42.42 | 99.1123 | -23 |
```

(compare the 42.42 and 99.1123 in the `to_markdown` table to the 42 and 99 in the plain old df)

Is this a bug or am I missing something about how to use `to_markdown`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like pandas uses [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) for this formatting.  If it's installed, you can use something like:

```
df.to_markdown(floatfmt=".0f")
```

output:

```
|    |   0 |   1 |   2 |
|---:|----:|----:|----:|
|  0 |   1 |   2 |   3 |
|  1 |  42 |  99 | -23 |
```

Comment: Aaaah, I missed: `**kwargs: These parameters will be passed to tabulate`. Thanks!